# Astropy table manipulation: How can I create a new table with rows grouped by values in a column?

Tags: python, tabular, astropy

I have a table with multiple rows and columns. One of the columns has  different numbers that repeat several times. How can I create a new astropy table which only stores the rows with the column that repeats a number more than, say, 3 times?

example:

table

[image]

Notice that 0129 repeats 3 times in column c, 2780 repeats 4 times in column c. I'd like my code to then create the new table:

modified table

[image]

I'm using the astropy module and specifically:

```
from astropy.table import Table
```

I am assuming I need to use a for loop to accomplish this task and ultimately the command

```
new_table.add_row(table[index])
```

Big picture, what I am trying to accomplish is this:

```
if column_c_value repeats >=3:
    new_table.add_row(table[index])
```

Thank you for your help! I'm kind of stuck here and would greatly appreciate insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Table grouping](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/operations.html#id2) functionality:

```
In [2]: t = Table([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
   ...:            [10, 11, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 12]],
   ...:            names=['a', 'id'])

In [3]: tg = t.group_by('id')

In [4]: tg.groups
Out[4]: <TableGroups indices=[0 3 5 7 8]>

In [6]: tg.groups.keys
Out[6]: 
<Table length=4>
  id 
int64
-----
   10
   11
   12
   13

In [7]: np.diff(tg.groups.indices)
Out[7]: array([3, 2, 2, 1])

In [8]: tg
Out[8]: 
<Table length=8>
  a     id 
int64 int64
----- -----
    1    10
    3    10
    4    10
    2    11
    5    11
    6    12
    8    12
    7    13

In [9]: ok = np.zeros(len(tg), dtype=bool)

In [10]: for i0, i1 in zip(tg.groups.indices[:-1], tg.groups.indices[1:]):
    ...:     if (i1 - i0) >= 3:
    ...:         ok[i0:i1] = True
    ...: tg3 = tg[ok]
    ...: tg3
    ...: 
Out[10]: 
<Table length=3>
  a     id 
int64 int64
----- -----
    1    10
    3    10
    4    10

In [12]: for tgg in tg.groups:
    ...:     if len(tgg) >= 2:
    ...:         print(tgg)  # or do something with it
    ...:         
 a   id
--- ---
  1  10
  3  10
  4  10
 a   id
--- ---
  2  11
  5  11
 a   id
--- ---
  6  12
  8  12
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution that uses less fancy tools than [@TomAldcroft's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50655758/8033585) solution and actually filters out short groups. Let's assume that the column with repeated elements is called `'id'` as in [@TomAldcroft's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50655758/8033585) solution. Then,

```python
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
min_repeats = 3 # Let's say selected rows must have 'id' repeated at least 3 times

cntr = Counter(t['id'])
repeated_elements = [k for k, v in cntr.items() if v >= min_repeats]
mask = np.in1d(t['id'], repeated_elements)
new_table = t[mask]
```